# How to filter (show/hide) with two or more values in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a the following html:

```
<input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="option_1">
<label for="check_1">Option 1</label>

<input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="option_2">
<label for="check_2">Option 2</label>

<input id="check_3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="option_3">
<label for="check_3">Option 3</label>

<input id="check_4" type="checkbox" name="check" value="option_4">
<label for="check_4">Option 4</label>

<div class="productsBox" data-tag="option_1 option_2 option_3">Product 1</div>

<div class="productsBox" data-tag="option_1 option_4">Product 2</div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
<script>
        window.onload=function(){
        $('input').on('change', function () {
          var $checked = $('input:checked');
          if ($checked.length) {
            $('.productsBox').hide();
            $checked.each(function () {
              var val = $(this).val();
                $('.productsBox').filter('[data-tag*="'+val+'"]').show();
            });
          } else {
            $('.productsBox').show();
          }
        });
        }
</script>
```

So, if option 1 and option 4 are checked, the divs with product 1 and product 2 are shown, because they both contain the values option_1 OR option_4.

However, I would like to see that if option 1 and option 4 are checked only product 2 is shown because it contains the values option_1 **AND** option_4.

Is that possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is (1) in how you're deciding which `.productsBox` elements to show and (2) that you're applying the `.filter().show()` inside your `.each()` function.

Instead, you should create the complete filter condition by looping through the checked items, *then* apply the filter+show. In addition, at least based on your example data, you should use the "Attribute Contains Word Selector" ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)) which is `~=` instead of the contains selector `*=`. The former will ensure that `option_10` is seen as distinct from `option_1` in your `data-tag` filter.

Complete working JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    var $checked = $("input:checked");
    var $checkedFilter = '';
    if ($checked.length) {
      $(".productsBox").hide();
      $checked.each(function() {
        $checkedFilter = $checkedFilter + '[data-tag~="' + $(this).val() + '"]';        
      });
      $(".productsBox").filter($checkedFilter).show();
    } else {
      $(".productsBox").show();
    }
  });
});
```

You can see I create a new string variable upfront called `checkedFilter`; this is where we'll build the dynamic filter for which `.productsBox` items to show. Then as we iterate through the checked checkboxes, we build the complete filter based on those items. In the example of `Option 1` and `Option 4` being checked, the value of `checkedFilter` is: `[data-tag~="option_1"][data-tag~="option_4"]`.

Then outside the each loop of checked items, we invoke the `.filter(checkedFilter).show()` using the `checkedFilter` variable.

Working CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzZEmd

If you select Options 1 & 4, only `Product 2` appears; if you then select as a 3rd option Option 3, no product elements are displayed because none have 1, 3 & 4. If you select 1, 2 & 3, only `Product 1` appears, etc.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much Stevangelista!